# Cauchy Theorem on Analytic Theorem (on Newman's Proof of Prime Number Theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem, P. 707
https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf

For $g(z) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-zt} dt$ ($Re(z) = 0$), $g_T (z) = \int_0^T f(t) e^{-zt} dt$, where $T>0$, $R>0$ and $\delta >0$ such that $C = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq R, Re(z) > -\delta\}$,

by Cauchy theorem, $g(0) - g_T (0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C (g(z) - g_T(z)) e^{zT} (1+\frac{z^2}{R^2}) \frac{dz}{z}$

Can anybody help me how the term $e^{zT} (1+\frac{z^2}{R^2})$ is appeared? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They’ve introduced this term as some kind of clever way to analytically control the size of the integral without actually changing its value, like a well-chosen weighting.

Cauchy’s theorem tells you the integral - including the mystery term - evaluates to the value of $(g(z)-g_T(z))e^{zT}(1+z^2/R^2)$ at $z=0$. But that’s still just $g(0)-g_T(0)$, so it’s fine! No change has been made to the value of integral, but the integral is easier to bound in size with these new terms.